# Javascript sort method

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am working with a bit of code on a website and I am trying to order the results by member id (I've left comments in the code below where this is) it doesnt seem to sort the order of the results though so I guess I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone know what the issue is, and perhaps how I could limit the amount of results shown to about 10 please?

```
var httpRequestObject = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "/Wcf/Search.svc/TestSearch",
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {

    if (response != null && response.d != null) {
        var data = response.d;
        if (data.ServiceOperationOutcome == 10) {

            var profileList = data.MemberList;
            if (profileList != null && profileList.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < profileList.length; i++) {
                    var profile = profileList[i];

                    // sort var
                    var memberId = (profile.MemberId);


                    if (profile != null) {
                        var clonedTemplate = $('.profile-slider #profile').clone();
                        $(clonedTemplate).removeAttr('style').removeAttr('id');
                        $(clonedTemplate).find('img').attr("src", profile.ThumbnailUrl).attr("alt", profile.Nickname).wrap('<a></a>');
                        $(clonedTemplate).appendTo('.profile-slider');

                        // sort
                        $(memberId).sort();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        else {
            alert("Error code " + String(data.ServiceOperationOutcome));
        }
    }

    else {
        alert("Null data");
    }
},

error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

});

Comment: what was your intention with `$(memberId).sort();`? what's `memberId` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As adeneo said, you probably want to sort the Member list.

```
profileList = profileList
  .filter(function (arg) {return arg !== null;}) // remove nulls
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.MemberId < b.MemberId ? -1 : 1; // the < operator works for numbers or strings
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't have a sort method, but there is `Array.sort()` which is probably what you're looking for, but profile seems to be an object inside the array `data.MemberList`, so you should probably sort that before iterating over it:

```
var profileList = data.MemberList; // array
profileList.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.MemberId.localeCompare(b.MemberId);
});

for (var i = 0; i < profileList.length; i++) {
   // do stuff to each item in the now sorted array
}
```